# Intent Service questions

Tags: android, android-intent, intentservice

Lets say if i were to have multiple calls of an intent service by `startService(intentservice)`, will it run multiple instances of the service together or is it being queued?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you call **startService** Multiple times, and the service is already running, its **onStart** method will be called everytime,  **onCreate** will call only once if it is not already present.
Single instance will be there fot the service.

see this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) , here it is clearly mentioned below part

" Note that multiple calls to Context.startService() do not nest (though they do result in multiple corresponding calls to onStartCommand()), so no matter how many times it is started a service will be stopped once Context.stopService() or stopSelf() is called; "

Comment: hey man thanks. then what is the different between service and intentservice? as both perform similarly just that intentservice is running on different thread?

Comment: IntentService will receive the Intents, launch a worker thread, and stop the service as appropriate. 
while Service can be running all the time. it depend on our app requirement which one we should use.

Answer (score 3):

IntentService is a special case of service.  It will queue requests and stop itself when all requests are processed.

Comment: @eyespyus : I agree with ericlee. Can you explain the queuing part. is there any document that discusses that?

Comment: Have a look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService